# How to structure graph database to represent a relational database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I understand that there is no point in trying to engineer a relational database into a graph database. They are both inherently different and thus their data should be organized differently.

However, I'm building a database documentation app using Neo4j. In this app, a user would be able to upload tables from a SQL database. One feature is that a user would be able to preview the first 10 rows of any table they choose.

My problem is: I don't know how to structure a relational database in my Neo4j database, such that I could write Cypher query to print out a table in relational format.

So far I tried:

```
(Database)-[HAS_TABLE]->(Ex_Table)
                                 `–[HAS_FIELD]->(id) ––––––[HAS_CELL]->(1)
                                 `–[HAS_FIELD]->(name)–––––[HAS_CELL]->(bob)
                                 `–[HAS_FIELD]->(password)–[HAS_CELL]->(pass)
```

and

```
(Database)-[HAS_TABLE]->(Ex_Table)
                                 `–[HAS_FIELD]->(id) –––––––\
                                 `–[HAS_FIELD]->(name)–––(HAS_ROW)->({id:1,name:bob,password: pass})
                                 `–[HAS_FIELD]->(password)––‘
```

**Question:** Are these correct? If so, how could I query `Ex_Table` using Cypher to print the first 10 rows? If not, how should I structure and query to get that result?

Note: I have to use a graph database.

Comment: Is printing out the first 10 lines your only use case? If so, then just store the first 10 lines of each table in a string property of the neo4j node for that table.

Comment: @cybersam For now, that's my only use case, but it would be nice to have a flexible solution, in case I wanted add/remove rows from the preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need more meta data round your graph to really make this work. I would adopt this approach to storing your data:

```
create pth= (d:Database {name: 'MyDB'})-[:HAS_TABLE]->(t:Table {name: 'Users'}),
(t)-[:HAS_COLUMN {order: 1}]->(c1:Column {name: 'Id'}),
(c1)-[:HAS_VALUE {row: 1}]->(v1:Value {value: '1'}),
(c1)-[:HAS_VALUE {row: 2}]->(v2:Value {value: '2'}),
(t)-[:HAS_COLUMN {order: 2}]->(c2:Column {name: 'Name'}),
(c2)-[:HAS_VALUE {row: 1}]->(v3:Value {value: 'Bob'}),
(c2)-[:HAS_VALUE {row: 2}]->(v4:Value {value: 'Jim'}),
(t)-[:HAS_COLUMN {order: 3}]->(c3:Column {name: 'Password'}),
(c3)-[:HAS_VALUE {row: 1}]->(v5:Value {value: 'password1'}),
(c3)-[:HAS_VALUE {row: 2}]->(v6:Value {value: 'SafePassword'})
```

This will give you a graph that looks like this:
[image]

Now you can retrive your table structure with a query like this:

```
match (t:Table {name: 'Users'})-[r:HAS_COLUMN]->(c:Column)
return t.name, c.name
order by r.order
```

To retrieve the sample rows for a table use a query like:

```
// Get the column names as a list
match (t:Table {name: 'Users'})-[r1:HAS_COLUMN]->(c:Column)
with 0 as rownum, r1.order as colnum, c.name as val order by colnum
with rownum, collect(val) as vals
return rownum, vals
union // will append the results of the 2nd match to the first
// Get the sample data values
match (t:Table {name: 'Users'})-[r1:HAS_COLUMN]->(c:Column)-[r2:HAS_VALUE]->(v:Value)
with r1.order as colnum, r2.row as rownum, v.value as val order by colnum
with rownum, collect(val) as vals order by rownum
return rownum, vals
```

which will collect the value nodes into the correct order by row.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful. In the table that returns from the query, would there be a way for each column to correspond to a column from the relational database? In other words, to have columns: `rownum`, `id`, `name`, and `password`? I tried indexing vals with `colnums` but each time I include `colnums` in the  second `WITH` clause, `vals` splits each index into its own row. @Marj

Comment: @dannyvelasquez In short, yes. The list of column data needs to be unwound from a list into individual items. It's 23:00 here and I need my beauty sleep. I'll have a look in the morning :-)

Comment: no worries! I just realized I wouldn't even need that solution. Yours works perfectly as is :) @Marj

Comment: Phew - glad about that as there's actually now way to pivot the output in Cypher. (You could write your own stored procedure.)
I've edited the query to return the sample data so that the first row contains a list of column names.